# Bash command not working in Python

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm trying to execute the next bash command either from Python or Perl:

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --credentials /home/jsti/.config/google-oauthlib-tool/credentials.json
--device-model-id 'pbx-assista' --device-id 'pbx' -i /tmp/google_audio1314_in.wav -o /tmp/google_audio1314_out.wav -v
```

Basically the idea is to send an audio to Google Assistant, after that, it should answer me the audio with another audio. I should receive an audio file as a response from Google Assistant but I don't receive it. There is no errors but the file does not arrive.

The command works properly if I execute it in the terminal.

Does anyone know what it is happening with this command?

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from asterisk.agi import *
import subprocess

command = "googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk"
oauth_dir = "/home/jsti/.config/google-oauthlib-tool/credentials.json"
audio_in = "/tmp/google_audio1314_in.wav"
audio_out = "google_audio1314_out.wav"

agi = AGI()
agi.verbose("python agi started")
callerId = agi.env['agi_callerid']
agi.verbose("call from %s" % callerId)

while True:
  args = [command, '--credentials', oauth_dir, '--device-model-id', '"pbx-assista"', '--device-id', '"pbx"', '-i', audio_in, '-o', audio_out, '-v'  ]
  subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Comment: I've already included the code in the question. Sorry for the late

Comment: I notice that you aren't using `wait()`, `call()`, or anything else that actually *lets the subprocess finish before proceeding*. I'd particularly suggest `subprocess.check_call(args)` to throw an exception in the event of a failure rather than letting them go unnoticed.

Comment: If that's really the end of your program after the `while` loop, and you've never waited for your programs to finish, then... well... *of course* they won't be able to finish before the script ends.

Comment: This is the end of the code for now because this is the most important part and it is still not working. I tried the next code but it did not work: process = subprocess.Popen(...)
process.wait()

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, You were right. The code works properly either by using "wait()" or "call()". Thank you.

Comment: John's answer is *also* correct -- to be completely equivalent to the bash command you include in the question (which has syntactic quotes around the words `pbx-assista` and `pbx` but no literal quotes anywhere), you would need to take the literal quotes out of your Python strings.

Comment: ...unless you're suppressing quote removal by doing something in the bash version you aren't showing us, like putting the command in a string and expanding it unquoted ([BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) goes into detail on why that practice is so error-prone).

Comment: As I told you before this is all the code for now. I've just found out that you and John were right. Basically the problem now is: I'm trying to connect my PBX to Google Assistant sending the file mentioned in the code and I should receive an answer but I don't know why the subprocess is not being executed, it looks like that code line is being skipped. Obviously, when I execute the program without using AGI, it works properly.

Comment: Are you logging stderr? My next step (after doing so, checking exit status explicitly, etc) would be to use sysdig or similar tooling to trace the live invocations; it's a lot to filter through, but will catch oddball environment-specific scenarios like SELinux constraints clamping down on asterisk subprocesses' permissions to make outbound network connections.

Comment: I did not know anything about what you just said. I will check it.

Comment: The credential file could not be accessed by asterisk user, that's why the command did not work properly. Now, it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in use here doesn't actually wait to allow the subprocess to exit (and doesn't look at whether it succeeded or not, and so can't detect and report errors).

Change:

```
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

...to...

```
subprocess.check_call(args)
```

...or...

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
```

---

Also, you'll want to change `'"pbx"'` to just `'pbx'`; the double quotes in the original bash version are syntactic, just like the single quotes in the Python version are -- you don't need literal quotes in addition to the syntactic ones. (Bash optionally allows syntactic quotes to be left out when they aren't needed to prevent unwanted expansion, make otherwise-syntactically-significant characters literal, or the like; with Python, they're always mandatory when defining a string)

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the double quotes around `"pbx-assista"` and `"pbx"`.

```
args = [command, '--credentials', oauth_dir, '--device-model-id', 'pbx-assista', '--device-id', 'pbx', '-i', audio_in, '-o', audio_out, '-v']
```

Comment: Good call -- I completely missed the literal quotes there. That said, I believe the OP may *also* have a problem insofar as they aren't waiting for their subprocesses to complete before their script exits.

Comment: I can't get rid of the double quotes. They are part of the command.

Comment: @Stiben, this answer is in fact correct insofar as it goes: If your command is genuinely written as `--device-id "pbx"` in shell, **no**, the double quotes are not literally part of it the argument list that the shell passes to the executable it runs; the shell treats those quotes as syntactic, and removes them before it starts your command. To make your quotes literal in shell, it would need to be `--device-id '"pbx"'`, and obviously, you aren't doing that.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, are you inclined to edit to cover the other issue as well, or should I add a competing answer?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Go for it.